# How to get number of followers of an instagram page without API

Tags: c#, download, webbrowser-control, raw-data

I am trying to get number of followers of a page programmatically either of exact number (eg 521356) or (521K) would do.

I have tried download data to download the entire page but I couldn't seem to find number of followers

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
            byte[] raw = wc.DownloadData("https://www.instagram.com/gallery.delband/");

            string webData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw);
            textBox1.Text = webData;
```

I would like to be able to get number of followers but I can't find the data using web browser method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you cannot get the instagram webpage like you see it in the browser without executing JavaScript. And `System.Net.WebClient` does not execute js.

But if you analyse the html source of the page, you'll see that the followers count is included within a `<meta>` tag with `name="description"`:

```html
<meta content="88.5k Followers, 1,412 Following, 785 Posts - See Instagram photos and videos from گالری نقره عیار ۹۲۵‌‌ ترکیه (@gallery.delband)" name="description" />
```

To grab this information from the source, use a regex:

```
var pattern = @"<meta content=\""([0-9k KMm\.,]+) Followers, .*\"" name=\""description\"" \/>";
var match = Regex.Match(webData, pattern);
var followers = match.Groups[1];
```

The pattern means: Find a string, that starts with `<meta content="`, followed by a dynamic string of the characters 0-9, k, K, M, m, ',', '.' or ' ' (the actual followers count) followed by the text " Followers", then any text, but ending with `name="description" />`. Because we parenthesized the dynamic part, the regex system is giving us this dynamic value as a group result.

Answer (score 1):

WebClient just makes a simple HTTP request which will return very little for a lot of sites these days. You basically get a page that tells the browser "Great, now get that javascript bundle over there to get started". So to get the information you are after you'll need something more advanced like [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io) to actually load the page and execute scripts and everything. Preferably you'd use [CefSharp.OffScreen](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.OffScreen/) as to not show a browser window. Then you can parse out the information you wanted.

Comment: yes web client has very limited options but above solution worked great.